# macOS : Accessibility Groups

Tags: macos, accessibility

In Apple's [TicTacToe sample project](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AccessibleTicTacToe/Introduction/Intro.html), the [AAPLTicTacToeBoardView class](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AccessibleTicTacToe/Listings/TicTacToe_AAPLTicTacToeBoardView_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014589-TicTacToe_AAPLTicTacToeBoardView_m-DontLinkElementID_11) conforms to the `NSAccessibilityGroup` protocol.  In its requisite implementation of `-accessibilityChildren`, the array of 9 children representing the 3x3=9 board squares is only created during the first call.  It is also cached to an ivar.  During subsequent calls, the cached ivar is returned.

TicTacToe is a somewhat special case.  In other applications, for example the Tag Cloud which I am working on, the array of children may be different on each call, and therefore should be recreated on each call, with no caching to an ivar.

In the TicTacToe example, I presume that this ivar/caching is only for performance.  Therefore, if I just remove AAPLTicTacToeBoardView.m line 177,

```
  if (_accessibilityChildren ==  nil)
```

which forces it to recreate the children on every call, I expect all should continue to work, maybe just imperceptibly slower.

Instead, I find that removing this line breaks behavior.  When the user navigates with QuickNav into the game board, now VoiceOver says that the "group is empty", even though `accessibilityChildren` is still being called repeatedly and returns 9 elements, albeit a different 9, new ones, on each call.

It is apparently the new elements which cause the problem.  If I modify `-accessibilityChildren` to return a copy of the cached array which contains, say, 4 of the original elements, and copies of the other 5 elements, VoiceOver tells me that the game board contains "4 items", and QuickNav steps through the 4 squares represented by original items, skipping the squares represented by copies.  If you'd like to see that for yourself, replace the last line of `-accessibilityChildren` (`return _accessibilityChildren;`) with the following:

```
NSMutableArray* answer = [NSMutableArray new];
NSInteger i = 0;
for (AAPLTicTacToeSquareAccessibilityElement* element in _accessibilityChildren) {
    /* AAPLTicTacToeSquareAccessibilityElement does not conform to
     NSCopying, so we copy properties "manually". */
    AAPLTicTacToeSquareAccessibilityElement* copy = [[AAPLTicTacToeSquareAccessibilityElement alloc] initWithRow:element.row
                                                                                                          column:element.column
                                                                                                        delegate:self.delegate];
    copy.accessibilityParent = self;
    copy.accessibilityFrameInParentSpace = element.accessibilityFrameInParentSpace;
    if (i%2 == 0) {
        [answer addObject:copy];
    }
    else {
        [answer addObject:element];
    }
    i++;
}

return answer;
```

My question: Why?  And what will happen in my real app, which has changing group elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, although I cannot find it in Apple documentation, the answer to this is implied by a comment in the implementation of -[AAPLTicTacToeBoardView accessibilityChildren].  It reads:

```
// hold onto the accessibility elements the entire time they are shown in the UI
```

I would expect the result of disobeying this to be a crash, not the missing accessibility elements described in my question.  But, for whatever reason, caching the elements to a ivar, and adding some slightly messy code to re-use unchanged elements during each invocation of -accessibilityChildren, solved the problem.  One wonders if there would be any trouble due to race conditions when elements are added or removed, but it seems to work OK.

This code happens to be open source, in case anyone is interested, look in -[RPTokenControl accessibilityChildren] in [this file](https://github.com/jerrykrinock/RPTokenControl/blob/master/RPTokenControlKit/RPTokenControl.m).